# How do I make mutually exclusive mob drops in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I would like to implement something where an entity, when killed, drops one and only one item from its list of mob drops. Changing the probabilities of each mob drop to (1/number of possible mob drops) would not work as other items would still have a chance to drop if one item was dropped.

Comment: Try taking a look at the code for creepers killed by skeletons? This might be something you have to do via modding.

Comment: @Corsaka do i use the `entries` json attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Use [mcstacker](https://mcstacker.net/) loot tables. You can then add them to minecraft data packs. Some instructions can be found here on [fandom](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_pack#Folder_structure).

Comment: Thanks. I've used that to make a sample loot table and then auto-generated the loot table with the sample loot table using Python.